# Why am I getting SMS and CALL_LOG warning in Google Play console, when my app DOESNT use anything even remotely close to these permissions?

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, sms, calllog

My app is just a simple calendar alarm app, and uses this permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR">
```

Yet I get this warning:

[image]

But I dont use any of these permissions as you can see above. Also, two more proofs:

- I only use default google support libraries, and even when I unpack
  final apk file, and inspect manifest manually, there are none other
  permission
- Also when I install app on phone, and check on phone => apps =>
  permissions, there are none permissions except those I listed.

It simply must be a bug or something, why I get this warning?

What can I do? I filled the form couple days ago, but google didnt even reply me...

EDIT: Even more weird is, displaying the warning is totally random. One day I saw warning, then I refresh page and it disappears. Then I could not see it a week, and then suddenly today I see it again. When I refresh page it always disappear, but later it shows again. Totally random.

Answer (score 2):

Check for any third-party library you are using they have this permission(You can check in the merged manifest).if not then don't worry about the warning.

Comment: I wrote it in my post - I unpacked manifest file from final apk file, and it only contains my permissions, nothing else. But I still see warning - randomly, one time its there, another time it disappears. I am really worrying google will remove my app, they already did plenty of similar faux pas to other developers and this is my only income and its very important to me...I even filled the form couple days ago, but they didnt reply. Total ignoration, and I dont think there is anything else I can do...

Comment: if you are not using that permission then need not to worry.

Comment: same is happened with me. I am also worrying about the google warning. I have not used those permission though.

Have you got any email from google. I did not get email from them.